# Create copy of record based on node that occurs multiple times

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement to create a copy of an XML file based on a field that occurs multiple times.

Input XML: There are two EmpEmployment nodes in the XML. I need to separate them and copy the rest of the nodes so that I have two PerPerson records with one EmpEmployment  each.

```
<PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
        <personalInfoNav>
            <PerPersonal/>
        </personalInfoNav>
        <nationalIdNav>
            <PerNationalId/>
        </nationalIdNav>
        <personIdExternal>AA</personIdExternal>
        <personEmpTerminationInfoNav>
            <PersonEmpTerminationInfo/>
        </personEmpTerminationInfoNav>
        <phoneNav>
            <PerPhone/>
        </phoneNav>
        <employmentNav>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <compInfoNav>
                    <EmpCompensation/>
                </compInfoNav>
                <jobInfoNav>
                    <EmpJob/>
                </jobInfoNav>
            </EmpEmployment>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <compInfoNav>
                    <EmpCompensation/>
                </compInfoNav>
                <jobInfoNav>
                    <EmpJob/>
                </jobInfoNav>
            </EmpEmployment>
        </employmentNav>
        <homeAddressNavDEFLT>
            <PerAddressDEFLT/>
        </homeAddressNavDEFLT>
    </PerPerson>
</PerPerson>
```

I am trying to do this using XSLT 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:hci="http://sap.com/it/" exclude-result-prefixes="hci">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <PerPerson>
            <xsl:for-each select="PerPerson/PerPerson">
                    <xsl:variable name="var_person" select="./*[not(name()='EmpEmployment')]"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="employmentNav/EmpEmployment">
                        <xsl:variable name="var_empInfo" select="."/>
                            <PerPerson>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="$var_person"/>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="$var_empInfo"/>
                        </PerPerson>
                    </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </PerPerson>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its not working as expected. I am unable to create the desired output below:

```
<PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
        <personalInfoNav>
            <PerPersonal/>
        </personalInfoNav>
        <nationalIdNav>
            <PerNationalId/>
        </nationalIdNav>
        <personIdExternal>AA</personIdExternal>
        <personEmpTerminationInfoNav>
            <PersonEmpTerminationInfo/>
        </personEmpTerminationInfoNav>
        <phoneNav>
            <PerPhone/>
        </phoneNav>
        <employmentNav>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <compInfoNav>
                    <EmpCompensation/>
                </compInfoNav>
                <jobInfoNav>
                    <EmpJob/>
                </jobInfoNav>
            </EmpEmployment>
        </employmentNav>
        <homeAddressNavDEFLT>
            <PerAddressDEFLT/>
        </homeAddressNavDEFLT>
    </PerPerson>
        <PerPerson>
        <personalInfoNav>
            <PerPersonal/>
        </personalInfoNav>
        <nationalIdNav>
            <PerNationalId/>
        </nationalIdNav>
        <personIdExternal>AA</personIdExternal>
        <personEmpTerminationInfoNav>
            <PersonEmpTerminationInfo/>
        </personEmpTerminationInfoNav>
        <phoneNav>
            <PerPhone/>
        </phoneNav>
        <employmentNav>
            <EmpEmployment>
                <compInfoNav>
                    <EmpCompensation/>
                </compInfoNav>
                <jobInfoNav>
                    <EmpJob/>
                </jobInfoNav>
            </EmpEmployment>
        </employmentNav>
        <homeAddressNavDEFLT>
            <PerAddressDEFLT/>
        </homeAddressNavDEFLT>
    </PerPerson>
</PerPerson>
```

Comment: The text says "XSLT 1.0" but the code shows `xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"`. Why is that?

Comment: @MartinHonnen The processor that I am using can support 2.0 but I was going for the 1.0 approach. Sorry about that

Comment: @michael.hor257k thank you for your answer. It works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/PerPerson">
    <PerPerson>
        <xsl:for-each select="PerPerson/employmentNav/EmpEmployment">
            <PerPerson>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../preceding-sibling::*"/>
                <employmentNav>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </employmentNav>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../following-sibling::*"/>
            </PerPerson>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </PerPerson>
</xsl:template>     

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 you can use [tunnel-parameters](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#tunnel-params).

And then just use the template macht engine like below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PerPerson/PerPerson">
    <xsl:variable name="person" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="employmentNav/EmpEmployment">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$person" mode="denormalize">
        <xsl:with-param name="position" as="xs:integer" select="position()" tunnel="yes"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="employmentNav" mode="denormalize">
    <xsl:param name="position" as="xs:integer" tunnel="yes"/>    
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="EmpEmployment[$position]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will further look into XSLT 2.0